# ActiveRecord (w/o Rails): How to configure a connection to an azure database

Tags: sql-server, ruby, azure, activerecord, azure-active-directory

Note - I have never stood up a ruby app like this from the ground up and I am also very unfamiliar with Azure.

I am trying to connect to an existing DB on hosted on Azure via ActiveRecord. I am using ActiveRecord independently of Rails so any convention magic will be unavailable to me. I am currently unable to connect to the database and am unsure if my code configuration is incorrect, if I haven't configured azure correctly, or perhaps my account doesn't have the correct permissions. With my lack of experience I am just unable to determine which is which.

I am currently getting the `Login Failed for user '<username>'` error from tiny-tds. I've quadruple checked my username and pass and confirmed it is the same credentials I am using to log into the DB from Azure Data Studio. I have also created an app registration from which I got our client id and secret. I'm pretty sure that using the same url for host and resource is not correct but I'm not sure what resource is tbh. With all that said here is my code snippet.

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'sqlserver',
  tenant_id: '<tenant_id>',
  client_id: '<client_id>',
  client_secret: '<client_secret>',
  resource: '<servername>.database.windows.net',
  active_directory_domain: '<domain> (got this from the primary domain field on the  overview screen in azure portal',
  host: '<servername>.database.windows.net',
  username: '<username>',
  password: '<pass>',
  database: '<db name>'
)

class IndividualProfiles < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'individual_profiles'
end

def run
  puts 'Start'
  puts IndividualProfiles.first
  puts 'End'
end

run
```

For reference:

1. activerecord (4.2.11.3)
2. activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.2.18)
3. tiny_tds (2.1.5)
4. freetds (v1.3.16)

Comment: Looks like your driver is doing SQL Auth, when you are wanting AAD Auth.  It's quite possible that driver doesn't support any flavor of AAD Auth.  Can you use the official Microsoft ODBC driver?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, by driver do you mean adapter? Edit. Nevermind. I googled it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your issue is here (as I do not use all those additional options) however I did notice you are not passing the `azure` option (which could be the cause of your failure).

There is a configuration in the `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem specifically for [Azure](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/blob/main/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb#L102). This is passed through to TinyTDS and without this configuration the connection will not work.

According to the TinyTDS [README](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#using-tinytds-with-azure)

> TinyTDS is fully tested with the Azure platform. You must set the azure: true connection option when connecting. This is needed to specify the default database name in the login packet since Azure has no notion of USE [database]. FreeTDS must be compiled with OpenSSL too.

My working configurations look akin to:

```
connection_options = {
  adapter: 'sqlserver',
  encoding: 'utf8',
  pool: 5,
  host: '[server].database.windows.net',
  database: [DATABASE_NAME],
  port: 1433,
  azure: true,
  timeout: YOUR_TIMEOUT_VALUE,
  username: ENV['SQL_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['SQL_PASSWORD']
}
```

If this does not work please add the following to your post:

- Your ActiveRecord version
- Your tiny_tds version
- Your FreeTDS Version

For Example I have the following working right now: (among other configurations)

- ActiveRecord (6.0.4)
- tiny_tds (2.1.5)
- FreeTDS (v1.00.27 - TDS version 7.3)

Comment: I've updated my post. Adding azure didn't fix it. Still getting the same error. When I log into Azure Data studio I'm using AD and not Sql Login. I presume then, that simply providing a user name and password will not be enough in this case. I figured I'd need some kind of client secrect. ChatGPT gave me those extra configuration options you didn't recognize and also gave me some steps for registering an app in azure. It seemed reasonable but perhaps it's led me astray.

Comment: engineersmnky, I used `my@email.com@myazureserver'. I had found someone mentioning that you needed `@myazureserver` after your username. However, perhaps that was just a placeholder and I needed something more specific. I'm pretty ignorant right now on what I'm doing so I wouldn't be surprised. Also, how do I check my TDS version?

Comment: What specifically am I looking for? Those queries come up blank for me so I'm trying to look in the Azure Portal under the Azure Active Directory. There is a lot here so I'm not 100%. However, I did try using the server name and database name and one of those threw a 'can't connect to server' and the other 'Login failed'.